# How I can get <td name="pname"> values on Edit button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

On button click I add items in td which I have created with jQuery.

```
 $("#ddproduct").click(function () {

         $('#prodcuttable tr:last').after('<tr><td name="pname">' + prodName + '</td> <td>' + prodQty + '</td> <td>' + prodUp + '</td> <td >' + prodQty * prodUp + '</td><td> <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm fa fa-edit" onclick="Editproduct()">&nbsp;&nbsp; Edit</button></td></tr>');

    });
```

I have tried this but can't get.

```
function Editproduct()
{
    alert("Hi");
    var ProductName = $(this).closest("tr").find("td[name='pname']").text();
    alert(ProductName);
}
```

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Comment: There is no HTML. Edit Button is also Created with Jquery in <td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `this` in the function like:

`onclick="Editproduct(this)"`. Then use that passed `this` in the function.

Try the following way:

```js
var i = 1;
$("#ddproduct").click(function () {
  var prodName = 'Product ' + i;
  var prodQty = 3;
  var prodUp = 10;
  $('#prodcuttable tr:last').after('<tr><td name="pname">' + prodName + '</td> <td>' + prodQty + '</td> <td>' + prodUp + '</td> <td >' + prodQty * prodUp + '</td><td> <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm fa fa-edit" onclick="Editproduct(this)">Edit</button></td></tr>'); 
  i++;
});

function Editproduct(that)
{
  var ProductName = $(that).closest("tr").find("td[name='pname']").text();
  alert(ProductName);
}
```

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="ddproduct">Add Product</button>
<table id="prodcuttable">
<tbody><tr></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sir I can't create button in this way i have to create button with jquery too Please check laste <td> in below code 
$('#prodcuttable tr:last').after('<tr><td name="pname">' + prodName + '</td> <td>' + prodQty + '</td> <td>' + prodUp + '</td> <td >' + prodQty * prodUp + '</td><td> <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm fa fa-edit" onclick="Editproduct()">&nbsp;&nbsp; Edit</button></td></tr>');

Comment: just want to get firts <td> value with edit button in last <td>

Comment: @SohailAsghar, the solution above is just doing that...Clicking the `Edit` button which is in the last `td` giving the text of first `td`.

Comment: Thanks Sir This is what I want to do.

Comment: @SohailAsghar, you are most welcome. Please accept the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you bind the event to the button.
With the way you have done it, *this* is referring to *window* and not the *button*. You could add *this* in the function call:
Instead of `onclick="Editproduct()"` use `onclick="Editproduct(this)"` and change the *Edutproduct* to accept and use that argument.

```js
 $("#ddproduct").click(function () {
 let prodName='Product A', prodQty=1, prodUp=6;
         $('#prodcuttable tr:last').after('<tr><td name="pname">' + prodName + '</td> <td>' + prodQty + '</td> <td>' + prodUp + '</td> <td >' + prodQty * prodUp + '</td><td> <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm fa fa-edit" onclick="Editproduct(this)">&nbsp;&nbsp; Edit</button></td></tr>');

    });

    function Editproduct(self)
    {
        var ProductName = $(self).closest("tr").find("td[name='pname']").text();
        alert(ProductName);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ddproduct">Add</button>
<table id="prodcuttable">
<tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sir I can't create button in this way i have to create button with jquery too
Please check laste <td> in below code
$('#prodcuttable tr:last').after('<tr><td name="pname">' + prodName + '</td> <td>' + prodQty + '</td> <td>' + prodUp + '</td> <td >' + prodQty * prodUp + '</td><td> <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm fa fa-edit" onclick="Editproduct()">&nbsp;&nbsp; Edit</button></td></tr>');

Comment: just want to get firts <td> value with edit button in last <td>

Comment: @SohailAsghar I assumed that you could figure out how to update the code and add *this*, but I have now updated it in the example.

Comment: Thanks Sir This is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that this is your HTML code

```
<button type="button" id="ddproduct">Click Me</button>
  <table border="1" id="prodcuttable">
    <thead>
      <th>PName</th>
      <th>PQty</th>
      <th>PUp</th>
      <th>PQ*PU</th>
      <th>Button</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td name="pname">Alexa</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm fa fa-edit mybtn">Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Use this jQuery code to get what you want to achieve. I hope this will help you achieve what you want.

```
$("#ddproduct").click(function () {    
$('#prodcuttable tbody tr:last').after('<tr><td name="pname" class="pname">Chrome</td> <td>5</td> <td>3</td> <td >15</td><td> <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm fa fa-edit mybtn">Edit</button></td></tr>');    
        });

$("#prodcuttable").on("click",".mybtn", Editproduct);

function Editproduct()
{
//     alert("Hi");
    var ProductName = $(this).parent().siblings("[name='pname']").text();
//     console.log(ProductName);
    alert(ProductName);
}
```

Fiddle Link: [JsFiddle](http://jsbin.com/bebicu/1/edit?html,js,output)

---

- I have added class to button - **mybtn**
- I am binding click even to button using .on() event of table using its id. [jQuery .on() - w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp)

Comment: Sir I can't create button in this way i have to create button with jquery too Please check laste <td> in below code $('#prodcuttable tr:last').after('<tr><td name="pname">' + prodName + '</td> <td>' + prodQty + '</td> <td>' + prodUp + '</td> <td >' + prodQty * prodUp + '</td><td> <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm fa fa-edit" onclick="Editproduct()">&nbsp;&nbsp; Edit</button></td></tr>');

Comment: just want to get firts <td> value with edit button in last <td>

Comment: Please check fiddle once again and answer as well. I hope I have solved your problem